# total number of triangles in $G$ and $G^C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that if G is a simple k-regular graph on n vertices then the total number of triangles in $G$ and $G^C$ is :
$n\choose 3$-$nk(n-k-1)/2$.
I can understand how $n\choose 3$ comes but doesn't it give the total number of triangles in $G$ and $G^C$?

I don't understand how to obtain   $nk(n-k-1)/2$.
Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are easy examples to show that the number of triangles in $G$ and $G^C$ can be less than $\binom{n}3$. For example, let $G=C_4$, the $4$-cycle: $G^C$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $K_2$, so neither $G$ nor $G^C$ contains any triangle, yet $\binom43=4$, not $0$. $\binom{n}3$ is simply the maximum possible number of triangles in $G$ and $G^C$.

To get the actual total number of triangles in $G$ and $G^C$, we need to count the triangles in $K_n$ that are not in $G$ **and** not in $G^C$. Let $u$ be any vertex; $\deg_Gu=k$, and $\deg_{G^C}u=n-k-1$. Thus, there are $k(n-k-1)$ ways to choose two edges incident at $u$ in such a way that one of them is in $G$ and the other in $G^C$. We can do this for each of the $n$ vertices, so as a first approximation we count $nk(n-k-1)$ triangles in $K_n$ that aren’t in $G$ or in $G^C$. However, we’ve counted every one of these triangles twice, so the actual number of such triangles is only $$\frac{nk(n-k-1)}2\;,$$ meaning that $G$ and $G^C$ between them really do contain $$\binom{n}3-\frac{nk(n-k-1)}2$$ triangles.

The spoiler-protected block below contains a proof that each of these ‘bad’ triangles is counted exactly twice, but you should try to find one for yourself before looking.

> To see why this is so, say that vertices $u,v$, and $w$ form a triangle that is in neither $G$ nor $G^C$. Then two of the edges $uv,uw$, and $vw$ must be in one of the complementary graphs $G$ and $G^C$, while the remaining edge is in the other. Without loss of generality suppose that $uv$ and $uw$ are in one of graphs, while $vw$ is in the other. Then this triangle got counted once at vertex $v$, when we chose edges $vu$ and $vw$, and once again at vertex $w$, when we chose edges $wu$ and $wv$. Those are the only two vertices at which it was counted, and it was counted only once at each of those vertices, so it was counted exactly twice.

Comment: When I look at graphs like $C_4,C_5$ I understand that `choose two edges incident at u in such a way that one of them is in G and the other in` $G^C$ forms a triangle  which is in  $K_n$ but not in G or $G^c$.But for any graph it's difficult for me to see how this happens.Is it like say we select an edge ,say $uk$ incident on u from $G^c$.That is ${n-k-1}\choose 1$.Then select a vertex $w$ which is incident to a edge in $u$ in $G$.Then the edges $wk$ and $wu$ are not in $G$ or $G^c$ but in $K_n$.The vertices $w,k,u$ form a triangle not in $G$ or $G^c$ but in $K_n$.

Comment: @sam_rox: I can’t make any sense of that, I’m afraid: you seem to be using $k$ for two different things. $k$ is the degree of each vertex of $G$, so what do you mean by an edge $wk$?

Comment: $uk$ should be something like $ul$ .But what I said is wrong as `edges wk and wu are not in G or Gc but in Kn` is wrong.I don't understand how `choose two edges incident at u in such a way that one of them is in G and the other in `$G^C$ `forms a triangle which is in` $K_n$ `but not in G or` $G^c$

Comment: @sam_rox: Start with a vertex $u$. Pick a vertex $v$ such that $uv$ is in $G$ and a vertex $w$ such that $uw$ is in $G^C$. Now consider the triangle $uvw$. It can’t be in $G$, because the edge $uw$ isn’t in $G$. It can’t be in $G^C$, because the edge $uv$ isn’t in $G^C$. And all of this is true irrespective of whether $vw$ is in $G$ or in $G^C$.

Comment: A simple thing it took me a long time to understand.Thanks for the answer and the help

Comment: @sam_rox: You’re welcome.